# Jython 2.7.0 with jersey

Tags: java, jython-2.7

I was using Jython standalone version 2.5.3 in my REST application. It was working fine. When I upgraded to Jython 2.7.0, I am getting  the following exception,

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.python.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Java xml classes were packaged and distributed with version 2.7.0. But if I understand it correctly Java SE comes with these classes. This issue is raised as a bug [here](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2478). In order to avoid this exception add the xalan processor dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Another solution would be to upgrade to the latest version of the jython-standalone jar. This issue is fixed in the latest release 2.7.1

Comment: Thanks Husain. When we use 2.7.1 we no need to use xalan.

Comment: Yes. In 2.7.1 distribution there is no reference to the java xml classes, so NO need to use xalan.